# Can't create socket using IO::Socket

Tags: perl, sockets

when I run the following code, the execution is just hanging there, No response at all.
does any of you can tell me what's wrong with the sample code?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Select;
use IO::Socket;

my $s = new IO::Socket (
                          LocalPort => 8889,
                          Proto  => 'tcp',
                          Listen => 16,
                          Reuse  => 1
                      );

die "could not create socket $!\n" unless $s;
```

Comment: What specifically do you mean, "just hanging there"?  What symptoms are you observing?  When I run the above code (under 5.8 or 5.10), I get a fatal exception thrown by the `new` constructor:  `IO::Socket: Cannot configure a generic socket at bad-socket.pl line 8`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you provide arguments to the IO::Socket constructor it demands a Domain argument.  Check out the full source [here](http://kobesearch.cpan.org/htdocs/IO/IO/Socket.pm.html), specifically the configure subroutine which gets called from the constructor if you've provided arguments.

```
sub new {
  ...
  return scalar(%arg) ? $sock->configure(\%arg)
        : $sock;
}

sub configure {
  my($sock,$arg) = @_;
  my $domain = delete $arg->{Domain};

  croak 'IO::Socket: Cannot configure a generic socket' unless defined $domain;
  ....
}
```

Perhaps you're thinking of IO::Socket::INET?

Answer (score 1):

> what's wrong with the sample code?

`IO::Socket` is a generic super class for Perl sockets.

You need to replace the `IO::Socket` with `IO::Socket::INET`.

Comment: btw, do the same mistake myself all the time.